# JavaScript. Uncaught ReferenceError: (object) is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to develop a web app where all the inputs are "disabled" and will only be enabled when the user is 18+. But the following error is happening:

Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange.

Help me pls!!

```js
function check(){
 var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  if (age >= 18) {
   document.getElementById ("city").disabled =false;
   document.getElementById ("state").disabled =false;
   document.getElementById ("country").disabled =false;
   document.getElementById ("submit").disabled =false;

 } else{
  document.getElementById ("city").disabled =true;
  document.getElementById ("state").disabled =true;
  document.getElementById ("country").disabled =true;
  document.getElementById ("submit").disabled =true;
 }
}
```

```css
html {
font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
height: 95%;
}

label, input {
padding: .5rem;
margin: 1rem;
}

input[type=text]:enabled {
background: #ffff00;
}

input[type='text']:disabled {
background: #E01E1E;
}

input[type="text"]:disabled::placeholder {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TW-LAB- Pratica11exe14.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" href="TW-LAB- Pratica11exe14.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <label>Name: <input type="text" placeholder="name"></label><br>
  <label>Age: <input type="number" placeholder="age" onchange="check()" id="age"></label><br>
  <label>City: <input type="text"  disabled="disabled" placeholder="city" id="city"></label><br>
  <label>State: <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="state" id="state"></label><br>
  <label>Country: <input type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Country" id="country"></label><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Ok" disabled="disabled" id="submit">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please add the Code, where you call the check-function?

Comment: Hey @Nikolaus thanks for your attention! The code is in the post. I call the check-function on Age input.

Comment: You should show your eventListener code for the input.onChange listener.  The problem could be there.

Comment: @RafaelMarques And the check-function is in the Pratica11exe14.js file?

Comment: @Nikolaus exactly !

Comment: The css is irrelevant to your referenceError question.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

## on event handlers vs. event listeners

In short, use **event listeners** not <del>**on event handlers**</del>

Read [**addEventListener vs onclick**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/2813224)

The on event attribute event handler (i.e. `<input onchange='check()'...`) must be out of function scope of `check()` or the change event isn't bound to the input. Don't really know and don't care since on events are discouraged. Use event listeners:

ex. `document.getElementById('age').addEventListener('change', check, false);`

The following demo has some added features to it which are explained within the comments. This is a fully functional `<form>`:

- Fill out the fields then click the <kbd>Ok</kbd> button.
- It will send your data to a test server.
- The page will change to display the server's response.
- Note that each entry is a key(`[name]`)/value(`[name].value`) ex. `"age": "21"`

### References

[HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

[Eloquent JavaScript: Form and Form Fields](https://eloquentjavascript.net/18_forms.html)

### Note

- ***tag*#*string*** = element with id attribute

  - ex. `form#info` is `<form id='info'>...`
- ***tag*[*string*]** = element with a name attribute

  - ex. `input[age]` is `<input name='age'`
- **[*string*]** = is just an attribute

  - ex. `[name]` is `name="name"`
- ***Form field***, ***form control***, and ***form element*** are terms referring to `<input>`s in this demo

### Demo

```js
/* Refer to HTMLFormControlsCollection on details
|| on how form elements are accessed
*/
// Reference the <form>
var form = document.forms.info;

// Reference all form controls of form#info
var input = form.elements;

/* Register the input[age] for input events
|| When a user inputs data run the callback
|| function check() and pass the value of
|| input[age] through
*/
input.age.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  check(this.value);
});

// check() function will take a given value...
function check(age) {

  // ...convert value to a real number.
  var consent = Number(age);

  // if number is greater or equal to 18...
  if (consent >= 18) {

    /* ...find the input[name] and fieldset#set
    || and set their [disabled] atteributes to
    || false
    */
    input.set.disabled = false;
    input.name.disabled = false;

    // Otherwise diable them
  } else {
    input.set.disabled = true;
    input.name.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 95%;
}

label,
input {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}


/* All labels are inline-block so they can sit next to
their inputs and push them to the right at the distance
of their widths. Widths are in ch units of measurement
which are roughly the width of a "0" of the specific
font. */

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3ch;
}

input[type=text]:enabled {
  background: #ffff00;
}

input[type='text']:disabled {
  background: #E01E1E;
}

input[type="text"]:disabled::placeholder {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <!--All form controls have been unwrapped from its 
<label> so it'll be easier to align everything see CSS
for details-->

  <!--Added form#info it will send all values of <input>s 
that have a [name] attribute-->
  <!--The [action] attribute value is a real test server
that will recieve data and send a response back.-->
  <form id='info' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post'>

    <!--input[name] is disabled and given [name='name']-->
    <label>Name: </label><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name='name' disabled><br>

    <!--input[age] has [min]/[max] attributes and
    [name='age']-->
    <label>Age: </label><input type="number" placeholder="Age" name="age" min='0' max='111'><br>

    <!--Added fieldset#set and is disabled. Any fields
    within fieldset#set is also disabled (they don't
    need to be set disabled individually)-->
    <fieldset id='set' disabled>

      <!--Just a title-->
      <legend>Contact Info</legend>

      <!--city[city]-->
      <label>City: </label><input type="text" placeholder="City" name="city"><br>

      <!--state[state]-->
      <label>State: </label><input type="text" placeholder="State" name="state"><br>

      <!--contry[country]-->
      <label>Country: </label><input type="text" placeholder="Country" name="country"><br>

      <!--By default a <input type='submit'> or a 
      <button type='submit'>...</button> will
      submit data when clicked automatically if it
      is within a <form> or has a [form] attribute
      with a form's #id as its value-->
      <input type="submit" value="Ok">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that the parameter of document.getElementById is a string. So instead of:

```
document.getElementById (city).disabled =false;
```

it would be:

```
document.getElementById ("city").disabled =false;
```

Comment: Well, now I noticed the error, it is not finding the method check. This is weird. Are you sure you are importing the right js? Maybe you could test to make this javascript code within <script></script> tags in your html code. If it works, than the problem is the path of this js file.

Comment: It is exactly this, because now your code is working here in the editor. Just one more thing, you should make an else statement to disable everything, case the user puts 18 and then types again an lower number.

Comment: weird! In the editor is working but on google chrome is not.

Comment: One last thing to try. Clean your chrome cache, because it likes to store your javascript files and not update it when you reload the page. It may solve your problem. Just press Ctrl + H, Clean navigation data(I don't know how it will be in english, but might be something like this) and then select cache, and clean it.

Comment: The check function is probably not in global scope. Is it inside something else, like a document.ready function?